# Load multiple footers in Magento 2 transactional emails

Tags: magento2, email-templates

I'm trying to figure out how to load a different **footer** on the **invoice emails.**

The default footer will be loaded with:

```
{{template config_path="design/email/footer_template"}}
```

This will load the template from /MY-THEME/Magento_Email/email/footer.html.

In my invoice template I would like to load:

```
{{template config_path="design/email/footer-invoice_template"}}
```

For this I have created a tempate: /MY-THEME/Magento_Email/email/footer-invoice.html.

But it isn't that easy.

What would be the best way to do this?

Comment: Alternatively you can put footer code directly in your invoice template.

Comment: @SHPatel added my answer.

Comment: @Pierre check and let me know your result

Comment: @MineshPatel, Your answer makes sense. I will try it coming week.

Answer (score 0):

Email Template in magento work based on 2 values.

> your template must be there in xml file OR in database.

For the first approach, You need to define and create your own email template for this in your custom module .for example `etc/email_templates.xml` from Module `module-email`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Email:etc/email_templates.xsd">
    <template id="design_email_header_template" label="Header" file="header.html" type="html" module="Magento_Email" area="frontend"/>
    <template id="design_email_footer_template" label="Footer" file="footer.html" type="html" module="Magento_Email" area="frontend"/>
</config>
```

and template under   `module-email/view/frontend/email`

**OR**

i have checked by dirty trick

Create new template from admin panel and grab value of `id` (increment id)

after that inserted entry in core_config_data

```
INSERT INTO `core_config_data` (`config_id`, `scope`, `scope_id`, `path`, `value`) VALUES (NULL, 'default', '0', 'design/email/footer-invoice_template', 'increment id');
```

in above case i have added `increment id` as 2 which is template id from DB which i have created

now you can place your template in any email

```
{{template config_path="design/email/footer-invoice_template"}}
```

it should work.

Answer (score 0):

First create your template under your custom module

> app/code/Vendor/MyModule/view/frontend/email/footer_invoice_template.html

Second to load the template from configuration

> app/code/Vendor/MyModule/etc/email_templates.xml

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Email:etc/email_templates.xsd">
    <template id="footer_invoice_template" label="Footer" file="footer_invoice_template.html" type="html" module="Vendor_MyModule" area="frontend"/>
 </config>
```

third to use that footer invoice template in our templates with one single line 
add this line of code under

> app/code/Vendor/MyModule/etc/config.xml

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Store:etc/config.xsd">
    <design>
        <footer_invoice>
            <email>                    
                <template>footer_invoice_template</template>
            </email>
         </footer_invoice>
      </design>
    </config>
```

suppose if you want load this template into another template,just

```
{{template config_path="design/email/footer_invoice_template"}}
```